# correct placement of window.setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsp

I am looking to call an ajax function periodically. Below is my code and this is not serving purpose at the moment. Could any one help if I placing the window.setTimeout() stmnt properly..

```
<script>
    var xmlhttp;
    function loadXMLDoc(url, cfunc)
    {
        var config='${config}';
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=cfunc;
        xmlhttp.open("GET",url+config,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }

window.onload=ajaxFunction1();

function ajaxFunction1()
{
    loadXMLDoc("TagDataRetrieval?config=",function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("myDiv1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;    
        }
    });
    window.setTimeout("ajaxFunction1()", 5000);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your code looks like it intends to call `ajaxFunction1()` every 5 seconds.  Is that the desire?  What is not working as desired?

Comment: call the callback using `cfunc()` - you lacked the `()`

Comment: yes, what is the issue with your code ? furthermore you can call setTimeout(ajaxFunction1,5000) directly no , need to evaluate a string.

Comment: @Joseph i dont think you need () when you register an eventHandler.

Comment: @joseph - there's no issue with how cfunc is assigned to onreadystatechange.  If it was changed to `cfunc()` it would not work properly.

Comment: You should set `window.onload = ajaxFunction1;` without the parentheses. Not sure if that has anything to do with the problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
    var xmlhttp;
    function loadXMLDoc(url, cfunc)
    {
        var config='${config}';
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=cfunc;
        xmlhttp.open("GET",url+config,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }

function ajaxFunction1()
{
    loadXMLDoc("TagDataRetrieval?config=",function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("myDiv1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;    
        }
    });
   setTimeout("ajaxFunction1()", 5000);
}
window.onload=ajaxFunction1();
</script>
```

Comment: Please explain why your answer will fix the problem. What's different? Is it just moving the `window.onload=ajaxFunction1()` to the end, because with JavaScript's function declaration hoisting that shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: Funtion is does not execute so its call after.

Comment: By using the parentheses at the end of `window.onload=ajaxFunction1();` it will be executed immediately rather than as an event handler and the result (in this case `undefined`) will be assigned as window.onload

Answer (score 0):

you can use below function insted of setTimeout

```
<script>
    var xmlhttp;
    function loadXMLDoc(url, cfunc)
    {
        var config='${config}';
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=cfunc;
        xmlhttp.open("GET",url+config,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }

function ajaxFunction1()
{
    loadXMLDoc("TagDataRetrieval?config=",function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("myDiv1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;    
        }
    });

}
setInterval("ajaxFunction1()",5000);
</script>
```